# HMM Tagging is not accurate in NLTK

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I have been trying to implement a simple POS tagger using HMM and came up with the following code.

```
 import nltk
 from nltk.corpus import treebank

train_data = treebank.tagged_sents()[:3000]

print train_data[0]
# [(u'Pierre', u'NNP'), (u'Vinken', u'NNP'), (u',', u','), (u'61', u'CD'), (u'years', u'NNS'), (u'old', u'JJ'), (u',', u','), ... ]

from nltk.tag import hmm

trainer = hmm.HiddenMarkovModelTrainer()
tagger = trainer.train_supervised(train_data)

print tagger

print tagger.tag("Alex was born in Connecticut .".split())
# [('Alex', u'NNP'), ('was', u'NNP'), ('born', u'NNP'), ('in', u'NNP'), ('Connecticut', u'NNP'), ('.', u'NNP')]

print tagger.tag("Joe met Joanne in Delhi .".split())
# [('Joe', u'NNP'), ('met', u'VBD'), ('Joanne', u'NNP'), ('in', u'IN'), ('Delhi', u'NNP'), ('.', u'NNP')]

print tagger.tag("Chicago is the birthplace of Ginny".split())
# [('Chicago', u'NNP'), ('is', u'VBZ'), ('the', u'DT'), ('birthplace', u'NNP'), ('of', u'NNP'), ('Ginny', u'NNP')]
```

As you can see (many)tags are pretty much off. Why is this? I think the train set is pretty big enough :| ...?

Also, there is only a **0.3** match with the gold standard when I run `tagger.evaluate(treebank.tagged_sents()[3000:])`

Also posted [here](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/1095):

Comment: 3000 sentences is not that big...

Comment: @b3000 But it should cover the statements I used to test :/ . Seriously, `was` as `NNP`?